# How can set a color on an image?

Tags: html, css

**I want to set a layer of transparent black color on an image like below.Tried in many ways.But nothing worked for me.Can i do it using CSS?**

HTML:

```
<img src="images/slider1.jpg" alt="slider1" />
```

CSS:

```
img {
    height: 634px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Want]

Comment: You want to go from the left image to the right image? Could you try to explain your question more?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a layer on top with a certain color? Or completely change the colors of the image with a filter of some sort?

Comment: Like top image... @DieVeenman

Comment: I still don't know what you want to achieve..

Comment: Yes i want a layer of a color on the image @vyx.ca

Comment: I want a layer of transparent black color on  image....@DieVeenman

Comment: Welcome to [**Stackoverflow**](http://stackoverflow.com), a community viz built for programmers by programmers, please go through its [**Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) section and visit also [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), It'll help you and other SO users too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the same effect by overlaying your image on an element with the color you want, then setting the opacity of the image.

CSS:

```
#image {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#container {
    background-color: black;
    display: table;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmA5H.jpg" alt="slider1" id="image" />
</div>
```

Note the `display: table`.  This causes the div to grow only to the size of its content, which is exactly what we want for an overlay effect.
Set the opacity of the image to `1 - x` where `x` is the opacity of the overlay you want.  For example, if you want a 30% opaque black overlay, set the opacity of the image to `0.7`.

Check out this fiddle to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/145h44um/